# Exclusão de linhas com labels repetidos em um DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Preciso excluir em um dataframe linhas que constam labals repetidos, conforme em destaque na *coluna* "**B**":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o resultado de como eu gostaria que ficasse após exclusão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo(a) à plataforma. E, desde já, sujiro a leitura dos seguintes artigos: [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1). Ambos artigos, vos ensinará como elaborar uma boa pergunta, evitando com isso, votos negativos e, até mesmo, de fechamento. Boa sorte! Aproveite todo nosso potencial e volte sempre!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, você pode usar [`df.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) para filtrar os campos. O import da pandas fica implicito e criação do dataframe também vou usar o seu exemplo que fica assim:

```
df_sem_duplicacao = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B'])
df_sem_duplicacao
```

O parâmetro `subset` recebe uma lista com o rótulo das colunas. Por padrão, `df.drop_duplicates()`, removendo somente as que sejam exatamente iguais. Mas não é isso que queremos, por isso uso o parâmetro `subset` para especificar onde eu desejo aplicar o filtro.

Answer (score 2):

Tende usar o [`.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) desta forma:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B'])
```